# Jquery selector on dropdown value case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to set a selected value on a dropdown. But before I do this I check if the selected value is present within the control.
To do this I use the following code:

```
var exists = 0 != $('#comp option[value="'+ value +'"]').length;
```

where value can be upper, lower case or mixed case. How can I rewrite this bit of code so it works with all sorts of casing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#comp option').each(function() {
   if(this.value.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase() ) { 
      // do something
   }
});
```

Comment: np. I would suggest maybe looking to see if there was a more performant solution to this. if this is the only form on your page, or it is named.. you can eliminate jQuery completely.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting for all just make the value to lower case when checking it.

```
value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: The values in the list are not lower case and I can't make them in this scenario.

Comment: But can you make them lower case just to check the values?  These don't have to change the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvalue = 'ONE';
$('select option').filter(function() {
    if(new RegExp(this.value, 'ig').test(myvalue))
        $(this).attr('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this approach.

```
var matchingValue = $('#select option').filter(function () { 
     return this.value.toLowerCase() == 'stackoverflow'; 
     } ).attr('value');    
$('#select').val(matchingValue);
```